# Data model for folders in Core Data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, data-modeling, directory

I'm trying to implement a folders and items data model in Core Data. It will be displayed in a table view. I'm using a "listItem" entity for the table view with these properties:

```
listItem
--------
isFolder (BOOL)
item (relationship to an Item)
folder (relationship to a Folder, if isFolder is true, otherwise nil)
```

My Folder and Item entities both have a name property and a dateCreated property. My Folder entity also has an "listItems" relationship containing more listItems. All listItems are contained in a parent Folder.

How can I ask a fetched results controller to use the name or dateCreated property to order the tableview, even though they are in different relationships? Do I have to make a copy of the name and dateCreated in listItem? Is there a better way to do this in Core Data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an new property to your entry CreationDate and use an SortDescriptor to order them.

Comment: The problem is that if I add a dateCreated property to the listItem, I have to duplicate it in either the Folder or Item and make sure they stay in sync. If instead I move everything I want to order by to the listItem, my listItems will grow to contain almost everything and I might as well just reuse empty Items as folders.